# retrieving a single value from sql table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I wish to retrieve a single value from this database I have created. For example, The user will select a Name from a drop down box (these names correspond to the name column in the database). The name chosen will be stored in a variable called name_value. I would like to know how to search the database for the name in name_value AND return ONLY the other text in the next column called Scientific, into another variable called new_name. I hope I explained that well?

```
  connection = sqlite3.connect("Cw.db")
  crsr = connection.cursor()
  crsr.execute("""CREATE TABLE Names(
               Name text,
               Scientific text)""")
```

Inserting these values: (There is more but its unnecessary to add them all)

```
  connection = sqlite3.connect("Cw.db")
  crsr = connection.cursor()
  crsr.execute("""INSERT INTO Names (Name, Scientific)
                  VALUES
                  ('Human', 'Homo Sapien');""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement in SQL can be used to query for rows with specific values, and to specify the columns to be returned.

In your case, the code would look something like this

```py
stmt = """\
SELECT Scientific 
  FROM Names
  WHERE Name = ?
  LIMIT 1
"""
name = 'Human'
crsr.execute(stmt, (name,))
new_name = crsr.fetchone()[0]
```

A few points to note:

- we use a `?` in the `SELECT` statement as a placeholder for the value that we are querying for
- we set `LIMIT 1` in the `SELECT` statement to ensure that at most only one row is returned, since you want to assign the result to a single variable.
- the value(s) passed to `crsr.execute` must be a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), even if there is only one value
- the return value of `crsr.fetchone` is a `tuple`, even though we are only fetching one column.